# GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSession event problems

Tags: c#, .net

I've implemented this class of Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts nuget package for monitoring the actions (play and pause) of a third party music player.

Everything works except that after some time the events are no longer triggered.

This is the code:

```
public void startMediaListener()
        {
             

                GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.RequestAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().CurrentSessionChanged += callbackSessionChanged;
                GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSession currentSession = GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.RequestAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().GetCurrentSession();
                if (currentSession  == null || !currentSession.SourceAppUserModelId.ToLower().Contains("appNameToMonitor"))
                    return;

                Console.WriteLine("Started"); 
                currentSession.PlaybackInfoChanged += callbackPlaybackStatus; 

                currentHashSession = currentSession.GetHashCode();
                serviceRunning = true;
            
            
        }
```

Event when session changed

```
private void callbackSessionChanged(GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager session, CurrentSessionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Session changed" + session.GetCurrentSession().GetHashCode().ToString());
            

            if (session.GetCurrentSession() == null || !session.GetCurrentSession().SourceAppUserModelId.ToLower().Contains("appNameToMonitor"))
                return;
 
            session.GetCurrentSession().PlaybackInfoChanged += callbackPlaybackStatus; 

            currentHashSession = session.GetCurrentSession().GetHashCode();
        }
```

Event for detecting pause/play

```
private void callbackPlaybackStatus(GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSession session, PlaybackInfoChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!session.SourceAppUserModelId.ToLower().Contains("spotify") || currentHashSession != session.GetHashCode())
                return;

            GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionPlaybackStatus status = session.GetPlaybackInfo().PlaybackStatus;
            double currentTime = session.GetTimelineProperties().LastUpdatedTime.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;


             //Do work...
        }
```

I also check the hashcode because if I listen to Spotify then youtube then Spotify again the 2 sessions of Spotify have different hashcode and it will trigger the event twice (when it works) and I want to monitor only the last one.

The problem is that in startMediaListener() I can find the session of my app and everything works for few minutes but after some time the callbackPlaybackStatus is no longer called and meanwhile no session changed so I suppose that the session is still up but not firing the event.

Can you help me solve this mistery?

Ps: I've tried to put everything inside a thread but this solution doesn't works.